# mysql UNION result has less rows than sum of table row counts

Tags: mysql, union, rowcount

I'm using `UNION` to get all names in different tables.
my tables has about 10000 rows all together.
but the query returns 468 rows!!
My query is:

```
SELECT name FROM `shopping` 
UNION 
SELECT name FROM stores 
UNION 
SELECT name FROM concert 
UNION 
SELECT val AS name FROM event 
UNION 
SELECT name FROM fastfood
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

UNION removes duplicate values. You probably want UNION ALL instead.